# Comparing 2D array of chars to 1D array of chars

Tags: java, arrays, compare

How can I compare this 2D array of chars to 1D array of char?

```
array1[0][0] = 'a', 
array1[0][4] = null,
array1[1][1] = null
array1[2][0] = 'b'
array1[3][5] = null
and so on 

 array2[0] = 'a'
 array2[1] = 'b'
 array2[2] = 'a'
```

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: compare to what? to each other? the elements? just to check whether the elements of the 1D array can be found in the other one? You should also know, a variable of type char can never be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a nested loop and check each time.

```
char[] array2 = new char[3];
array2[0] = 'a';
array2[1] = 'b';
array2[2] = 'a';
char[][] array1 = new char[6][6];
array1[0][0] = 'a';
array1[0][4] = 'q';
array1[1][1] = 'r';
array1[2][0] = 'b';
array1[3][5] = 's';
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; ++i) {
    char ch = array2[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array1[j].length; ++k) {
            if (ch == array1[j][k])
                System.out.println("array2[" + i + "] matches with array1[" + j + "][" + k + "] with char being " + ch);
        }
    }
}

Output :
array2[0] matches with array1[0][0] with char being a
array2[1] matches with array1[2][0] with char being b
array2[2] matches with array1[0][0] with char being a
```